# connecting to exchange server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exchange-server, pop3

I am using this code to connect to my exchange server using POP3.

I am trying to retrieve an inbox of basically emails that have not been read  however, i am just getting a bunch of gibberish and its reading an email.

Can you help me modify my code to just read the most recent messages.

```
Try
    tcpClient.Connect(hostName, 110)
    Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = tcpClient.GetStream()
    Dim bytes(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize) As Byte
    Dim sendBytes As Byte()

    networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize))

    sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("User " + userName + vbCrLf)
    networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)

    sTemp = networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize))

    sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Pass " + userPassword + vbCrLf)
    networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length) 

    sTemp = networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize))

    sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("STAT" + vbCrLf)
    networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)

    sTemp = networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize))

    sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("RETR " + messageNumber + vbCrLf)
    networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)

    networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize))
    returnMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
    EmailContent.Text = returnMessage

    sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("QUIT" + vbCrLf)
    networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)

    tcpClient.Close()
Catch ex As Exception
    EmailContent.Text = "Could not retrieve email or your inbox is empty"
End Try
```

when i use top instead of retr i get this

```
+OK X-MimeOLE: Produced By Microsoft Exchange V6.5 Received: by xch0p.com id <01CB58CE.A6A4EA@p.com>; Mon, 20 Sep 2010 09:17:07 -0500 MIME-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="----_=_NextPart_001_01CB58CE.81A6A4EA" Content-class: urn:content-classes:message Subject: What we need to do?? Date: Mon, 20 Sep 2010 09:17:07 -0500 Message-ID: <58BFAFC0B9884245A005DFC0C3F73B8604188DF0@abc-exch01.rp.com> X-MS-Has-Attach: X-MS-TNEF-Correlator: Thread-Topic: What we need to do?? Thread-Index: ActV7LH3Idm5VVuiRXqkVkVTKZy6fgC4Xsmw X-Priority: 1 Priority: Urgent Importance: high Sensitivity: Company-Confidential From: "Mooq" To: "Everyone " .
```

Comment: What version of Exchange? Can you not just use the Exchange APIs instead of doing low level network streams?

Comment: 6.5 and im not sure i am new to this

Comment: You're code actually works just fine for me. Are you getting an error. Can you show us what the "gibberish" is? I don't have an exchange server to test it against but I tested it but since you're just using POP3 that shouldn't matter.

Comment: it works fine but it only returns a certain message  in this case its the first one ever i want it to return only the last 10 messages. and not the entire message just the sender and the subject and date

Comment: actually it may be better if i use imap4 or does it not matter

Comment: If you only want the headers to you can sent the `TOP 1` command

Comment: Also, to get the first 10 messages you can just use `RETR 1`, `RETR 2`, etc.

Comment: hmm the top command works but retrieves a bunch of random characters

Comment: actually i got it to work but its comes out with so much data why cant i just get the sender and the subject and the date

Answer (score 1):

Why do it yourself, how about a library?  http://sourceforge.net/projects/hpop/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's an option for you (have to be using Exchange 2007 or 2010) but I've been using Exchange Web Services in a few recent projects and it works very well.

Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119.aspx